# Travis CI failing to build with RSpec errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, travis-ci

My Travis CI builds are failing when it tries to run RSpec. Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: ruby
script:
- export RAILS_ENV=test
- bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load db:test:prepare
- bundle exec rake cucumber
- bundle exec rspec
```

The first three script steps complete successfully and I get `Done. Your build exited with 0.` ([here](https://travis-ci.org/deeprog/goalify/builds/83443599))

But when I add the fourth step (`bundle exec rspec`) I get `Done. Your build exited with 1.` ([here](https://travis-ci.org/deeprog/goalify/builds/83444088))

The error in the build (`uninitialized constant CommentsController (NameError)`) comes from the first line in th first file in the "spec/" folder (`comments_controller_spec.rb`). Here are the error details from Travis:

```
$ bundle exec rspec
/home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant CommentsController (NameError)
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /home/travis/build/deeprog/goalify/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
The command "bundle exec rspec" exited with 1.
```

I am stumped about this error. I have tried adding `require 'rails-helper'`/`require 'spec_helper'` to the top of the spec, but that didn't help. I've also tried running `rake` instead of `bundle exec rspec`, but that gives the same error.

The app currently lives at a relative root (`'/goalify'`), so to get the tests to run locally I had to set `config.relative_url_root = nil` in `test.rb`. But removing that line doesn't fix it on Travis, either. I've also added any required environment variables to Travis.

Here is some more info:

**Gemfile:**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'travis'
end
```

**.rspec**

```
--color
--format documentation
--require spec_helper
--require rails_helper
```

And here is the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/deeprog/goalify).

Comment: add require 'rails_helper' on the first line of https://github.com/deeprog/goalify/blob/master/spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb

Comment: @sam-d I've tried that before but it worked right away this time! Make it an answer and I'll accept it - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @sam-d for pointing out the answer!

I added `require 'rails_helper'` to `comments_controller_spec.rb` and it started working. Which I thought was weird because I didn't need that extra `require` locally. Then I realized my `.rspec` file (where I send my `require`s to RSpec) is in my `.gitignore` file - so Travis wasn't seeing the includes. I added all the switches to the fourth step in the scripts section so my new `travis.yml` is:

```
script:
- export RAILS_ENV=test
- bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load db:test:prepare
- bundle exec rake cucumber
- bundle exec rspec --color --format documentation --require spec_helper --require rails_helper
```

And now I get `The command "bundle exec rspec --color --format documentation --require spec_helper --require rails_helper" exited with 0.` from Travis.